# Get consecutive count on repeated values with complex partition by in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, partition-by

Given a set of 3 columns (blue columns: student, semester, grade) I need to calculate for how many consecutive semesters has each student had the same grade (green column) using a query in Postgres.

(first consecutive semester with avg 8: consec = 1. second consec semester with avg 8: consec = 2...)

Sample data fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v31a5Bpere26tXQb5L1fFJ/0

Expected result:

[image]

I have tried using

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by student)

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by avg_grade)

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by student, avg_grade)

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by student, semester)
```

But none of the above get the expected results.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gap and islands problem.  The simplest method is probably to define the groups using the difference between a sequence per grade and semester.  Then use `row_number()` on more time:

```
select g.*,
       row_number() over (partition by student, avg_grade, semester - seqnum order by semester) as consec_avg
from (select g.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student, avg_grade order by semester) as seqnum
      from grades
     ) g;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uybKwV18nHEZNP8x1TrdGv/0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon! I was not that simple. I took a full course on window fns and partitions and never got this advanced.

*The db fiddle link has one more line than the code in the answer. The full code for everyone else is the following: 

`select g.*,
       row_number() over (partition by student, avg_grade, semester - seqnum order by semester) as consec_avg
from (select g.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student, avg_grade order by semester) as seqnum
      from grades g
     ) g
order by student desc, semester`